# How to find last div is visible?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 30 Question which are constructed in 30 divs I am loading 10 at a time when it loads last div I want to disable NEXT button
I tried following code

```
    if ($(".collapsible").last().is(':visible')){
    alert("dsfsd");
}
```

or

```
 if ($(".collapsible").last().css('display') === 'block'){
        alert("dsfsd");
    }
```

But not Working Can any one help me.

Comment: Consider posting all the relevant code.

Comment: It depends on your html, you need to show html

Comment: Please provide SO Snippet with relevant code to better help you out.

Comment: put the question number as an id of each question div. then test `if($("#lastQuestionNumber")){alert("dsfsd");}`

Comment: `$(".collapsible").last().is(':visible')` should work, it is correct. When are you running the code? What does the HTML look like? Please post a complete example.

Comment: here is a simple pagination example that you can follow http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/e5xd02yy/

Comment: hey jogesh_pi thanks a lot this is what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can compare  the length of visible collapsible elements with collapsible element every time you load them:

```
 if ($(".collapsible:visible").length==$(".collapsible").length){
    alert("dsfsd");//hide next button
 }
```

Comment: i can't give it hard coded as I can increase no. of Q 
But got solution from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/e5xd02yy/ thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code seems right for me. My only suggestion is to check where you put your if statement, it should be below your showing function..

JS:

```
$("input").click(function(){ 
    $("div:visible").last().next().show();
    //make sure you check after showing the div
    if($("div").last().is(":visible")){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zdy9zsLb/) for you..

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the below code. It may help you. I have done pagination also. Hiding the next button only on the last page.

```
var total = $('.question').length;
var show = 10;
var start = 1;

for(var i=0; i<total; i++) {
   if( i == show ) break;
   $('.question').eq(i).show();
}

$('.next').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var start1 = show * start; start++;
   nextPage(start1, show);
});

function nextPage(start, limit) {
   for(var i=0, j=start; start<total; i++, j++) {
       if( i == show ) break;
       $('.question').eq(j).show(); //show only 10 questions in the current page
       $('.question').eq( (j-show) ).hide(); //hide all other questions
       if(j=== total)
       $('.next').hide(); //hide button with class "next"
    }
}
```